# Python Files IndexError

Tags: python

My Code:

```
def readData(fname):
    year = []
    loc = []

    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f.read():
            curr_line = line.split('\t')
            print(curr_line)
            year.append(curr_line[0])
            loc.append(curr_line[1])

    return (year,loc)

def findLocation(yrList,locList,year):
   yrList = [str(yr) for yr in yrList]
   if year not in yrList:
       return "Not found."
   return locList[yrList.find(str(year))]

def main():
    yr, loc = readData('olympics.txt')
    print(yr)
    print(loc)
    x = input("Enter year: ")
    print(findLocation(yr,loc,x))
```

After doing the main() function, it gives me this error after typing in the year

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Homework5.py", line 25, in main
    print(findLocation(yr,loc,x))
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\Homework5.py", line 18, in findLocation
    return locList[yrList.find(year)]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Can somebody explain what is wrong with my code and why I get this error?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and strip everything from that wall of text that does not belong to the problem.

Comment: You need to tell us what you're actually trying to do (and NOT what your homework problem is). What happens when you run the program?

Comment: If you're getting an exception, we really need to see the full traceback of the exception. (We probably don't need to know the assignment at all.)

Comment: This is too much information, can you cut this down to just the parts of the problem that are related?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Because of the feedback, I attempted this question to be more specific. The traceback is added as well. Thanks for the input so far

Comment: Nvm, your code is incorrectly indented so I missed something. Anyway, a regular list does not have a find method, which is also what the error is telling you. What do you want to do?

Comment: i define yrList in findLocation. I'm relatively new to programming so I may be misunderstanding a lot of this.

Comment: If you're looking for the index of a value in a list you can use `yrList.index(year)`, which will either return the index of the element in the list or throw a ValueError which you'll have to catch.

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do was use yrList.index instead of yrList.find and I got the result I was looking for. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Writing my solution as an answer and not just a comment for future visitors:

If you're looking for the index of a value in a list you can use `yrList.index(year)`, which will either return the index of the element in the list or throw a ValueError which you'll have to catch, instead of `.find` that does not exist.